# What are (interesting) examples of theorems in Analysis in which $\mathbb R^n$ is the only exceptional case?

Tags: analysis, soft-question, big-list

I can’t recall so many statements in Mathematical Analysis that hold for a certain class of possibly unbounded subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ (or $\mathbb C^n$) with the only exception being the whole space. Some examples that I have in mind are:

1. [The Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem)
2. [Liouville’s theorem for harmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville%27s_theorem) (which is somehow related to the Riemann mapping theorem). In fact, at least for $n\geq 3$, the theorem never holds for any proper open subset $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$, as the fundamental solution to the Laplace equation is smooth away from the origin. (**edit**: actually one also has to assume that $\Omega$ is not dense)
3. The strict inclusion between the Sobolev spaces $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$,
   $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ with $1\leq p<\infty$ (this one is probably more
   naturally seen as the contrapositive of the density of test
   functions in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$, but still sounded strange to me
   while I was studying it)

Do you have interesting examples of theorems or statements in Analysis that hold for a certain class of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ (open, measurable, convex,…) which does not a priori exclude $\mathbb R^n$, but for which $\mathbb R^n$ is actually the only exeptional case in which the statement breaks down?

Comment: In the title I mean that $\mathbb R^n$ is the only exception among a class of its subsets, not among some generic class of spaces

Comment: I don't quite follow the question.  Since $(0,1)^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, I would imagine almost any "problem" with a result holding in $\mathbb{R}^n$ would also translate to it failing in $(0,1)^n$ as well.

Comment: @TedShifrin _What_ is a mischaracterization of RMT?

Comment: @Randall , the two examples above don’t have the property that you say of translating well between diffeomorphic open sets of $\mathbb R^n$. You clearly have to work in a setting that distinguishes $\mathbb R^n$ from other subsets, so you need a problem that works with a bit more than just the differentiable structure. Just an example: if you take a PDE on $\mathbb R^n$ and you consider its push-forward through an arbitrary diffeomorphism, the PDE might change drastically. For instances, you can exhibit non-constant bounded harmonic functions on $(0,1)$, but not on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I started to type, stopped in the middle, and thought I'd deleted.

Comment: Since your claim about Liouville's theorem needs a small correction, you may want to rethink the question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you. I don’t know… In that specific case one could use an equivalence relation on open sets where two open sets are equivalent iff their closures coincide (or if one is dense in the other). That way, the only exception is precisely the equivalence class of $\mathbb R^n$. Even with this correction, the example sounds close to the spirit of the question (to me), but maybe I could write this

Comment: Yes, that could be a way to deal with the modification. If you are expecting an answer to your question, it is best to make it as clear as possible by an edit.